Find sum of factorials divisible by the largest possible prime squared
Let $n$ be a positive integer.
Consider the following maximization problem :
Use each of the factorials $1,2,3!,\cdots ,n!$ at most once such that the resulting sum is divisible by $p^2$ , where $p$ is the largest prime possible.
The naive method is to verify all $2^n$ subsets which is done by this PARI/GP - routine :
gp > maxi=0;forvec(z=vector(10,j,[0,1]),s=sum(j=1,length(z),z[j]*j!);if(s>1,w=component(factorint(s),1)~;v=select(m->Mod(s,m^2)==0,w);if(length(v)>0,p=vecmax(v);if(p>maxi,maxi=p;y=select(m->z[m]==1,[1..length(z)]);print(y,"  ",s,"  ",p)))))


For $n=5$ , the best is $11^2\mid 5!+1!$

For $n=10$ , the best is $449^2\mid 9!+8!+2!$

For $n=20$ , the best is
[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
1401602635449
394631

The best I found so far for $n=32$ is
[9, 11, 14, 16, 17, 19, 24, 26, 27]
11292781360068712833636746880
949523



Question : Is there anything better than exhaustive search ? Is finding the maximum prime $p$  for a given $n$ an NP-complete problem ?


The largest prime $p$ with the desired property ($p^2$ divides the sum) , if the largest factorial we can use is $n!$

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 19, 20, 24, 26, 27]  11292781362501238232077715913  1812091

There are some numerical examples in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709479/why-does-a-sum-of-factorials-behave-differently-from-single-factorials

You can write it as subset-sum for every p, so it wouldn't surprise me if it's NP-complete.

@KaleBhodre For $~n~$ equal to some fixed positive integer, let $~S~$ denote the set $~{1!, 2!, \cdots, n!}.$  Then, while the problem statement is (perhaps) somewhat poorly worded, this is compensated for by the given examples.  What is the largest prime $~p~$ such that there exists some non-empty subset $~T~$ of $~S,~$ such that $$p^2 ~| ~\left[ ~\sum_{x \in T} x ~\right] ~?$$

I used such approach:
for given $n$ (currently, $n=32$), loop through prime numbers $p$ starting from certain value $p_0$ to, theoretically, $\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n k!}$;
and for these $(n,p)$ construct 2 sets:

set $A$: contains all possible sums out of $1!, 2!, \ldots, a!$ ($\bmod p^2$);

set $B$: contains all possible sums out of $(a+1)!, (a+2)!, \ldots, n!$ ($\bmod p^2$);

where $a = \lfloor n/2\rfloor$.
After sorting $A$ and $B$, find such $\alpha\in A$, $\beta \in B$ (if such ones exist), that $\alpha + \beta \equiv 0 (\bmod p^2)$. Sorting is helpful just to don't use pairwise comparison between $A$ and $B$.
This way, we can use simple $64$-bit numbers instead of large numbers arithmetics.
Anyway, the complexity of the calculations remains to growth exponentially with $n$, unfortunately.
My current best such prime divisor for $n=32$ (and $n=31$) is $p=336500677$:
the set: [7, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 25, 27, 31],
the expression: 7!+11!+12!+16!+17!+18!+25!+27!+31!,
the sum: 8222849558558583286187694074635440.


This is the cut-in-half approach of 2-sum in subset sum, right? I think randomized subset sum algorithms may work here.

Yes, absolutely: cut-in-half in subset sum problem, right. Yep, maybe randomized algos could provide new records faster; didn't try that yet.
