Different version of Brocard's problem
By chance, I learned about Brocard's problem, one of the unsolved problems in mathematics. I've been thinking about this problem and I'm wondering if it's okay to think about it this way.

We are trying to find a pair of integers of the form $y^2=x+1$. In this case, if we convert to the form $y=\sqrt{x+1}$, we can automatically find the pair of integers by finding the value of $\sqrt{x+1}$ that is an integer.

Thinking in the same way as above, I thought of approaching Brocard's problem by changing the equation $n!+1=m^2$ to the gamma function $\Gamma({n+1})=m^2-1$, and converting it to $m=\sqrt{\Gamma({n+1})+1}$ to find a pair where $\sqrt{\Gamma({n+1})+1}$ is an integer.
I was thinking about comparing the graph of the gamma function with the graph of the integer lattice to find the integer solution. Is there a mathematical error in this idea?

The catch is that Brocards problem has been verified upto a very large $n$ (Unfortunately , Wikipedia mentions a quadrillion instead of a power of $10$ , so I am not quite sure how large the search limit actually is , but it is huge). And for such a large $n$ , determining whether the presented function gives an integer is extremely difficult. Hence this approach won't help , but in principle there is nothing wrong about it.

@Peter I see.. Thank you so much for your comment!

you could plot the gamma function and the quadratic $y=x^2-1$. You will notice that there is only one instersection of these two curves at $4!$. We know that $5!$ and $7$ are also part of the Brocard's problem but I consider them as an accident and $4!$ in my humble opinion is the only true Brocard's number.

@user25406 Why is then $4!$ not an "accident" to speak with your words ? Just because the other solutions are "too large for graphing it" ?

@Peter, $5!$ is not too large to graph. You can simply scroll until you get to the $5!=120$ and you will see yourself that there is no intersection. $7$ is too large. $4!$ is not an accident because it can be written as $4!=1234=46=k(k+2)$ with $k=4$.  It's the only number involving number $4$ and $6$ on two diagonals parallel to the square diagonal of the multiplication table. For $5!$ and $7!$, you need to do more work to put them in the form $k*(k+2)$.

@user25406 It anyway depends on the scale and the accuracy of the graph. It is anyway a bad idea to try to detect integer points with a graphical method (where errors are inevitable) instead of simply computing them , at some point the graphical method is utterly useless anyway since we cannot in general distinguish between integer points and non integer points.

Peter, I agree with what you said about scale and accuracy of graph but in our case we are looking for points common to the two curves $n!$ and $y=x^2-1$. The only common point is that of $4!$. After that the two curves diverge and will never meet again.

Some more data on this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709479/why-does-a-sum-of-factorials-behave-differently-from-single-factorials
